# I got an error when using apscheduler with mongodb jobstores based on tornado

Tags: python, tornado, apscheduler

```
# get function like this:
@gen.coroutine
def get(self, url=None):
    if not url:
        url = "https://www.baidu.com/"
    res = yield self.client.fetch(url)
    raise gen.Return(res.body)

# add_job method:
self.sdu.add_job(
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback,
    'interval',
    seconds=delta_time,
    args=[get],
)
```

I start apscheduler in Tornado Application:

```
self.sdu = scheduler.SchedulerWrapper()  
self.sdu.start()
```

and the error log is:
ValueError:

> This Job cannot be serialized since the reference to its callable
>   (>) could
>   not be determined. Consider giving a textual reference
>   (module:function name) instead.

don't know how to solve this problem, asking for ur help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a bound method as the target function of a job. That will not work with a persistent job store. Instead, create a new function as the target which will then get the global IOLoop and start the coroutine.

Comment: `self.sdu.add_job(
            self.job_runner,
            "interval",
            id=job_id,
            args=["job_id", "url"],
            # kwargs={"job_id": job_id, "url": url},
            **schedule_keywords
        )` so I write like this, but it still doesn't work